# What is the top altitude of the class delta KEDC? It looks like it's not depicted on the VFR sectional chart

Tags: visual-flight-rules, class-d-airspace

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? I usually see a [-#] that denotes the airspace above a class delta. I believe KEDC (Austin Executive) is a class delta based on the chart supplement.

Attached is the VFR sectional from vfrmap.com:

[image: KEDC VFR Sectional]

Answer (score 5):

This looks odd to me.

The supplement (3 Jan 2019) does indicate class D operations:

> AIRSPACE: CLASS D svc 1200–0400Z‡ other times CLASS E.

But the current (August 2018) [Airspace Designations and Reporting Points](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.11C.pdf) doesn't list class D airspace for it, only class E.  This matches the sectional shown.

When I look at another part-time airport (like Drake Field/FYV), the airspace is listed both as class D and class E as expected, and the height of the class D is given.

Perhaps something needs to be updated?

UPDATE
Yes, looks like the control tower opened at KEDC Feb 2018.  It should eventually be charted.  Until then, NOTAMS...

> KEDC NOTAM:
>
> !EDC 01/001 EDC AIRSPACE CLASS G SFC AREA CHANGED TO CLASS
>   D 1901031200-PERM

And the [update section](https://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/03jan2019/SC_rear_03jan2019.pdf) of the supplement.

> 8 Nov 2018 No Major Changes.
>
> 3 Jan 2019 Add AUSTIN, TX Class D: That airspace extending upward from the
>   surface to and including **3,000 feet MSL** within a 4.1-mile radius of
>   Austin Executive Airport, excluding the Austin Class C airspace. This
>   Class D airspace area is effective during the specific dates and times
>   established in advance by a Notice to Airmen. Revise AUSTIN, TX Class
>   E: That airspace extending upward from 700 feet above the surface
>   within a 14-mile radius of 30º17´55″ N, 97º42´06″W ....

I don't know why the airspace change is marked as Jan 2019 when the tower opened in Feb.

Comment: Sectionals only get updated every 24 weeks. The San Antonio sectional here was published Nov 8 2018 and is due for update on Apr 25 2019.  Changes between chart updates are included in the Chart supplement every 28 days. The change shows in the Supplement but not the chart,so I would assume the change occurred after the freeze date for the Nov 2018 chart changes. It should show up on the Apr 25 2019 Sectional.

Comment: If this were a recent change that's simply not yet charted, I would expect it to be mentioned in the A/FD updates area.  I don't see any mention there.  https://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/03jan2019/SC_rear_03jan2019.pdf.

Comment: It's listed as an add on Page 422. Since it says effective by NOTAM, it may not be charted or the NOTAM may be the interim 'solution' waiting for the chart update.   
AIRSPACE  
8 Nov 2018 No Major Changes.
3 Jan 2019 Add AUSTIN, TX Class D: That airspace extending upward from the surface to and including 3,000 feet MSL within a 4.1-mile radius of Austin Executive Airport, excluding the Austin Class C airspace. This Class D airspace area is effective during the specific dates and times established in advance by a Notice to Airmen.

Comment: Man, I looked at the right document, but that didn't help me read it.  I must have read the wrong page and not realized it.  That's exactly what I wanted to see.

Answer (score 1):

This interested me enough to actually call the tower in order to hear some kind of explanation from a tower controller. The only explanation I got was that the ceiling, when active class D, was 3000 feet. I asked how anyone would know this and she told me that it was "published." I'm not sure where it's published but the conclusion we both came to is that the charts coming out in the next cycle (in a few days) should have the 3000 ft ceiling denotation.

Comment: I guess "published" means in the supplement and the NOTAM.

Comment: I don't think the controller even really knew too much about where to find this information otherwise they could have just said check the NOTAMs.